# Error when including file in Visual Prolog v5.1

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

I have 2 files on Prolog.

ROUTE.PRO:

```
DOMAINS
company=symbol
city=string
transport=symbol

PREDICATES
route(company, city, city, transport).

CLAUSES
route(amtrac, "New York", "Boston", train).
route(ndg_transit, "New York", "Philadelphia", train).
route(amtrac, "Boston", "Portland", train).
route(grayhound, "Boston", "Portland", bus).
route(amtrac, "New York", "Washington", train).
route(peoples, "New York", "Washington", airplane).
route(peoples, "London", "New York", airplane).
```

TRAVEL_1.PRO:

```
:- include("E:\\Labs\\MSHI\\lab1\\code\\ROUTE.PRO").

CLAUSES
competitor(Company1, Company2) :-
    serves(Company1, Route),
    serves(Company2, Route),
    Company1 \== Company2,
    Company1 @< Company2.

GOAL
serves(amtrac, chicago_to_new_york).
serves(peoples, boston_to_chicago).
serves(peoples, chicago_to_san_francisco).
```

when trying to connect a file ROUTE.PRO to TRAVEL_1.PRO the following error will occur:
[image]

I'm using Visual Prolog v5.1.